# Background worker hangs whole application

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, freeze

Ok here's the pretty light code:

```
// 
// numConfigsBindingSource
// 
this.numConfigsBindingSource.DataMember = "NumConfigs";
this.numConfigsBindingSource.DataSource = this.DSNumConfigs;

// Grid
this.GridNumConfigs.DataSource = this.numConfigsBindingSource;

// 
// DSNumConfigs
// 
this.DSNumConfigs.DataSetName = "DSNumConfigs";
this.DSNumConfigs.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
// 
// numConfigsTableAdapter
// 
this.numConfigsTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = false;
//
// 
// DSConfigNumbers
// 
this.DSConfigNumbers.DataSetName = "DSConfigNumbers";
this.DSConfigNumbers.EnforceConstraints = false;
this.DSConfigNumbers.SchemaSerializationMode =       System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.numConfigsTableAdapter.Fill(this.DSNumConfigs.NumConfigs);                    
}
```

Then I run this code under VS2010 it works find but when I just run release application it's hanging. But if I rewrite this code that isn't using `BackgroundWorkers` it's works fine.
Do I need some effort to clearly release background worker? I have tried to lock worker class in `Form1_Load` it isn't provide any success. Also have tried to lock `this.DSNumConfigs` in `DoWork` and also no any successful stuff.

Comment: Do you have any controls bound to the table adapter? A short but *complete* example would really help here...

Comment: Yes, I have a grid bounded to DSNumConfigs

Comment: on my website there is an article about running background threads on windows forms ... it may be of some help to you although its not using background workers. Anyway ... hope this provides something you can try ... http://www.idevforfun.com/index.php/2010/01/10/windows-ui-threading/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're doing something unsafe: you're accessing the UI on a non-UI thread. You're not doing so *explicitly*, but your UI is bound to your table adapter.

You may want to unbind, *then* run the background worker, then (on the completed event) rebind the UI.

I'm surprised that it's not throwing an exception when you run it in the debugger, to be honest...

Comment: Thanks so much John! Could you please give me some sample how to do it?

Comment: @kseen: Which bit are you finding difficult? I can't say I do much GUI stuff, but I'd expect both binding and unbinding to be pretty straightforward...

Comment: oh, yeah, it was much easier than I was expecting :)