# Background worker makes my application hang

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, backgroundworker

I am using a background worker which brings the next 100 records from the database and binds it to the grid at runtime. It is working fine but my application hangs although grid is displayed properly. I am using the background worker for all other screens for the same purpose. If I open any screen it hangs.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690767/background-worker-hangs-whole-application) also but it doesn't help.

Here is my code for DoWork event handler.

```
while (bgStop)
 {
     e.Result = addNewRecords();
     if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Result) == false)
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
         backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
         bgStop = false;
         killBGWorker();
     } 
 }
```

in `addNewRecords` I am merging the datatable to data source of grid.

Comment: You can't interact with the UI-thread from the backgroundworker

Answer (score 1):

It would be beneficial to trace if you have posted some of your code or exception it throws.

However, I guess you might be trying to update your UI related activities in non ui thread Or you might be doing something unsafe.

Simply, place your database related read operation within `DoWorkEventHandler` and UI related within `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler`. You may also check thread affinity before updating your UI controls.

Comment: Please refer my code which i have append with the question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interact with the UI-thread from the backgroundworker. You can however use a delegate to update your UI-control.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDataGridView();
}

delegate void UpdateDataGridViewDelegate(string args);

private void UpdateDataGridView(string args)
{
   if (dataGridView.InvokeRequired)
       dataGridView.Invoke(new UpdateDataGridViewDelegate(UpdateDataGridView), args);
   else
    {
        //update datagridview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for infinite loop in the worker. Break the loop on some condition.